# How to simulate Mac flooding attack in Cisco Packet Tracer?

Tags: cisco, switch, mac-address, packet-tracer

I'm trying to see effectiveness of port security on **Cisco** switches using simulations in **Packet Tracer**.but first I need to run some **Mac flooding address** attacks on switches in Packet Tracer. Can anyone tell me how can I simulate this attack in Packet Tracer?

Comment: "_I'm trying to see effectiveness of port security on Cisco switches using simulations in Packet Tracer._" That is _not_ how to do it. Packet Tracer is a simple simulation to help you pas the CCNA. It is missing many features of real Cisco equipment and software, and you could not tell if something you find is real or an effect of Packet Tracer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have searched allot for this so I put it hear maybe it can save time for others like me.

I have understood that **hosts** in **Packet Tracer** are not really configurable to do much works so I can't install packages or run special codes on them.

Instead I decided to use **GNS3** which i can have my own configured **VMs** on hosts and so I can run my desired attack scripts for simulation.
There are lots of tutorials on how to create your own VMs in GNS3.

Comment: This is much better than Packet Tracer, but it can still give you results that are not real. There are companies that will rent you racks of real Cisco equipment to which to can connect and configure. You will then have real Cisco hardware (not a simulation or emulation) and software from which you can get real results.